# How use backticks in npm scripts on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, shell, npm

My workflow is npm scripts, running commands in my node_modules along with simple shell commands.

Unfortunately this makes it difficult for windows users due to my using backticks in some commands (see Example below).  I have a pull request volunteering to convert to [shellJS/shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) for my build so my repo will build cross-platform but we can't figure out a solution for backticks in npm scripts.

Question:

- What shell does npm use? On windows it appears to not support backticks.
- Is there a workaround? Piping doesn't help, alas, rm, mkdir etc don't use stdin.

Example backtick use in package.json:

```
  "mkdirs": [
    "dist/AS",
    "libs",
    "models/scripts"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "mkdirs": "mkdir -p `bin/pkgkey.js mkdirs`",
    ....
```

.. where the `bin/pkgkey.js mkdirs` script simply returns the mkdirs array. This may seem odd but it's great for organizing npm-style workflow.

The pkgkey script (simplified):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs')
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json'))
const key = process.argv[2]
let val = json[key]
if (Array.isArray(val)) val = val.join(' ')

process.stdout.write(val)
```

Comment: Not a windows user but can't you escape the quotes: `"mkdirs": "mkdir -p \"bin/pkgkey.js mkdirs\"",`

Comment: @Dominik The OP mentioned backticks: `\``, but yeah.

Comment: Yeah he said they are not working so move to quotes that work in all shells... no?

Comment: The point of backticks in this case is to evaluate in place, not to pass a string. quotes work in all shells to pass a string but they don't evaluate on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Check cross-env, don't know if it will work for your use case but I use it to make npm scripts platform independent

```
npm i --save-dev cross-env

"mkdirs": "cross-env mkdir -p ..."
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env